# How to make photo one on top of the other in a block of span?

Tags: html

basically pic1 will have the height of pic2+pic3.

And all pic1,2,3 will be in the same block, pic2 and pic3 and pic1 will have the same width

pic1 on the left and pic2,3 on the right.

My code, which doesn't work...please help:

```
<div class ="row">

<span class ="row_1">
<img src="image/under.png" />
</span>

<span class ="row_2">
<img src="image/under.png" />
<img src="image/under.png" />

</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row_1 img {
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
.row_2 img {
display: inline-block;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: And the css that you have tried?

Comment: Additionally you haven't closed your span tags: </span>. Do you want to far align the images contained within row_2 to the right?

Comment: @trickyzter oops. U are right,   Not far, i want it to be close to the row_1, basically,  you can think of it as like 2 pictures, one next to another, but on the right picture there has a cut on the middle that makes it into 2 pic, one on top of the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. In order to adhere to W3C standard's block level elements cannot be nested inside those that are inline, however inline-block allow's you to do this. The only thing to note is that the display value of inline-block is not completely browser backward compatible, specifically IE7 and below.

```
.row_1 img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.row_2 img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.row_1,
.row_2{
    display: inline-block;
}

.row_2 img{
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: block;
}

.row_2 img:first-child{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: he's looking to stack the row2 on top of row1, no?

Comment: I believe this is what he wants.

Comment: Just add padding to the image, see above for an example.

Comment: thank you so much, i am new to this so forgive me for asking easy quesiton :D

Comment: No worries, we all have to start somewhere. ;)